# WPF TabControl when changed selected item MediaUriElement hides

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, mediaelement

I have TabControl and I want in content of TabItems have videos. 
I have method that add videos to content of tab:

```
private void AddVideosFromListToTab(IEnumerable<VideoClass> list, TabItem tab)
    {
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        foreach (
            var media in
                list.Select(
                    video =>
                    MediaUriElementHelper.CreatePreviewMediaElementUri(video.SamplePath(), 200, 150, mediaPreviewControls,
                                                                       mediaPlayer_MouseDown)))
        {
            stackPanel.Children.Add(media);
        }
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock {Text = "Some text"});
        tab.Content = stackPanel;
    }
```

And this is my method for creating Media with video. I am using MediaUriElement because it's better in performance.

```
    public static MediaUriElement CreatePreviewMediaElementUri(string sourceFile, int width, int height, List<MediaUriElement> listMedias, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler mouseDown)
    {
        var media = new MediaUriElement();
        media.BeginInit();
        media.Width = width;
        media.Height = height;
        media.Margin = new Thickness(20);
        media.Volume = 0;
        media.LoadedBehavior = WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.MediaPlayers.MediaState.Play;
        media.MouseDown += mouseDown;
        media.Loop = true;
        media.Source = new Uri(sourceFile);
        media.EndInit();
        listMedias.Add(media);
        return media;
    }
```

When app loads it's okay but when I select another tab there are no videos and when I go back to first tab there aren't too anymore. I added some text and that is there always. So the problem is with MediaUriElement. Does someone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that because normal TabConrol has only one contentPresenter it dicards the previous content. 
If so, this should work:
[Stop TabControl from recreating its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794151/stop-tabcontrol-from-recreating-its-children)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it without using TabControlEx (cause it didn't work for me either).
I've used Datatemplates and templateselector in order to switch between tabs.

Xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:MainTabViewDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myMainContentTemplateSelector" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Dashboard">
        <views:DashboardView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SystemHealth">
        <views:SystemHealthView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MainTabs}"
                Margin="0,33,0,0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                SelectedIndex="0"
                 Width="auto" 
                Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyleMain}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myMainContentTemplateSelector}"
                Padding="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabControl.Background>

            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SystemHealthAndDashboard;component/Images/innerBackground.png"/>

            </TabControl.Background>
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

The DataTemplateSelector:

```
 public class MainTabViewDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        switch ((item as TabInfoEntity).TabIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    return element.FindResource("Dashboard") as DataTemplate;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    return element.FindResource("SystemHealth") as DataTemplate;
                }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

TabInfoEntity class (list of objects of this type are the itemsource of the TabControl):

public class TabInfoEntity
    {
        public TabInfoEntity()
        {

```
    }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private int tabindex;

    public int TabIndex
    {
        get { return tabindex; }
        set { tabindex = value; }
    }
}
```