# Content of the tab items. How many instances are created internally?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a tab control with a content template defined. This content template has a text block *tbInfo* (just to simplify, in my case that is a user control). Then I create N tabs. Do I have internally N instances of *tbInfo* or is it just the same one refreshing when I change selected tab?

Answer (score 1):

`TabControl` recreates a view when user changes tab. This means, that whenever you select tab, you will have a fresh new control. This can be a real trouble when your views are very heavy. Then recreating a view can take quite long time.

This is why some people work around this, by storing created views and just showing them or not. See [this question as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794151/stop-tabcontrol-from-recreating-its-children).

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. But when you say, it recreates a view, you mean it displays another instance of control or it updates the same instance of the control?

Comment: When items have different templates (i.e. when you use `DataTemplateSelector`) new instances are created for sure. I don't know whether this applies to the situation, when template is the same for all items.