# How to preserve the overall state of the MDITabControl view as it is swapped for another view?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'll be referencing the custom `TabControl` used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802346/1633308), so please check that out first.

That answer gives me the MDI-type view that I am after.  The tabs themselves preserve nicely, while that view is on-screen.

However, that is just one of two views that the `MainWindow` can display.  The other is a navigation view with icons that the user can click to open different sections, which open as tabs in the `TabControl`.

So the question is, how can I preserve the state of the entire `TabControl` (MDI) view itself, in addition to what the linked answer does?  In other words, I need to be able to freely flip back and forth between this navigation view, and the `TabControl` view without losing the state of either one.  But the switching causes the MDI view to `Unload`, and then I lose the state of all tabs (MDI views).

The `MainWindow` is using this as the content holder for the two views it can display:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

The `CurrentViewModel` is assigned an instance of either the `MDITabControlViewModel` or `HomeViewModel`.

Comment: You could use the same tab control instead of the `ContentControl` as your view container. Just make the tab headers invisible and switch the tabs between navigation and MDI container.

Comment: @dymanoid A little "slight of hand"?  An interesting approach, and I'll give that some thought.

Comment: @dymanoid I have attempted to implement what you've suggested, but I've hit a wall.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311882/how-can-i-conditionally-hide-the-tabpanel-portion-of-a-tabcontrol-in-its-entiret) if you're interested in helping further.