# How can I conditionally hide the TabPanel portion of a TabControl in its entirety?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabpanel

I've found a lot of variations of this question, but the conversation always seems to revolve around the individual `TabItems`, and not the `TabPanel` as a thing unto itself.

My main window has a `TabControl` on it.  The tabs are views.  One of those views is special...a navigation display, whereas all of the others are the "sections" that the nav view can open.

What I am trying to accomplish is that when the user is viewing the nav view, the tabs all go away.  I.e. hide the whole `TabPanel` instead of having to hide each `TabItem` one-by-one.  While viewing any other page, the tabs show, for easy movement between views.

I created this question in response to a suggestion made on [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218739/how-to-preserve-the-overall-state-of-the-mditabcontrol-view-as-it-is-swapped-for).

The problem I have is that the `TabPanel` does not seem to have a `Template` that I can override in order to do something like a `DataTrigger` bound to the `Visibility` property.  The closest I have gotten is a plain old `Style.Setter`.

Any suggestions on how to get what I am after?

Comment: Would you consider using a `TreeView` and then `Control` with specific `ControlTemplate`s? This would allow you to use specific `UserControl`s or whatever you are using now to display the information based on the type of a `ViewModel`. But that depends on the structure of your app. Could you provide some code so we know what we are dealing with? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically provided the answer yourself - the right combination is to use a `Style` together with a `DataTrigger`. The trick is to define a `Style` with `TargetType` set to `{x:Type TabPanel}`, and put it as a resource of the `TabControl` - that way the style will be applied to the `TabPanel` (because it's an *implicit style*). Here's an example:

```
<TabControl (...)>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}"
                             Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    (...)
</TabControl>
```

In this example the panel will be collapsed while the first item is selected.

Comment: That works beautifully.  I thought I had tried putting that `DataTrigger` everywhere, but obviously not in this particular slot.  Sometimes there are just too many ways to skin the WPF cat.  Many thanks.