# MVVM: Extending a Read-Only Model with IsExpanded and IsSelected in TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Consider a `ViewModel` that exposes a tree defined in the `Model`, which is then data-bound to a `TreeView`. The tree is rather large and the model is used directly because it is essentially read-only with regards to the view. Now, the `TreeView` lives under a `TabControl` in the VisualTree, so an issue at this point is that the `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties aren't preserved when switching between tabs. One hesitates to add these boolean properties to each node in the `Model`, as this should be extended in the `ViewModel` as a matter of principle. The tree is composed of polymorphic nodes, so if we were to create a `ViewModel` node type that derives from the tree node types and adds these properties, it seems this would result in some hairy code in the `ViewModel`:

That is, if the tree has an abstract `NodeBase`, and then derived types `Node1`, `Node1`, ... `NodeN` (the `Model`'s `Node`s). The `ViewModel` then has to encapsulate these nodes, so when creating a `ViewModelNode`, if it has a reference to `Node` and also references to child `ViewModelNode`'s for each descendent `ViewModelNode` that encapsulates each descendent `Model`'s Node all the way down the tree, maintaining these child references in the `ViewModel` identically to how they are maintained in the `Model`, along with a reference to the `Model`. i.e. all references in the `Model` nodes are replicated in the `ViewModel` nodes, in order for each `Model` node to be encapsulated by a `ViewModel` node. The existence of redundant references such as this, even if handled in the `ViewModelNode`'s constructor, just smells bad.

What is the most accepted means to extend each node in a tree in this scenario, without wholesale replication of the references as stated above? (And to a lesser point, is the mere mention of using the model directly by the view an unforgivable crime, or is this forgiven due to the circumstances?)

Comment: *"if we were to create a ViewModel node type that derives from the tree node types and adds these properties, it seems this would result in some hairy code in the MVVM ... wholesale replication of the tree"* -- you lost me there. Please clarify, in a separate paragraph.

Comment: There's no inherent harm in exposing the model to the view, if it actually makes things *simpler*. It usually won't make things simpler. When you start writing weird workarounds because of it, it's time to refactor.

Comment: You could maybe choose another way and just make the `TreeView` persist its state (don't unload on `TabPage` change). For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794151/stop-tabcontrol-from-recreating-its-children).

Comment: Thanks @dymanoid for the link - that is working excellently as a workaround. I had become so accustomed to the TreeView rebuilding on every tab change that I had actually become blind to this as a cause of my woes. @Ed is right that eventually I may need to extend the `Model` as a  `ViewModel` in other ways and at that point I may have to refactor. I'm just not sure what I'd aim for in a refactor, so I've revised the question with what I mean by "hairy" per @Ed's request. Thanks to both for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is perhaps an argument to be made that implementing those Boolean properties on the Model is OK, but personally I would look to creating ViewModels for each Model that's going to be in the `TreeView`. One advantage of doing so would perhaps be an increase in scalability, should you ever decide to implement more functionality related to the `TreeView`.

I think it depends on how much you are actually doing with the `TreeView` (within your app), but I do think the more you're doing, the stronger the argument for a ViewModel-based solution.

With regards to the hairy code, you could perhaps circumvent this to a degree by using an `interface` to describe your `TreeView` members, e.g.:

```
public interface IMyTreeViewItem
{
    bool TreeViewItemIsSelected { get; set; }
    bool TreeViewItemIsExpanded { get; set; }

    // Further potential properties

    string TreeViewItemHeaderText { get; set; }
    List<IMyTreeViewItem> TreeViewItemChildren { get; set; }
}
```

This approach can be used to ensure that your `TreeView` members are properly "subscribed". There's also then an option to reference the `interface` type in XAML, for example, as the `TargetType` of a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the `TreeView`.

Comment: So here's where I meant hairy: The `ViewModel` would implement the interface, and not the `Model`. The `Model` is a tree of varying node types, and my concern is how to avoid having a `ViewModel` that has excessive code with no value added other than to "glue" the `View` to the complex `Model`.

Comment: If the Model itself is already your tree, and it is intended to be read-only, I would probably implement the entire thing as a property on some ViewModel, and bind to that.

Comment: This works until the moment I need to add properties to each node to support the TreeViewItems.

Comment: To me that's the argument for having these structures as ViewModels. It would depend on what kind of properties they are, but if they seem to be "app-based", and wouldn't really exist outside of the app for any reason, they belong on a ViewModel. In my view the following article gives a good explanation of what a Model should be: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/.