# Scrollbar position shared between tab pages in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My application uses a TabControl (with items bound to a collection), where each tab has a data grid (whose lines are bound to a collection on the tab model).

When I scroll the view on one of the tabs, that same scroll action is applied to all the other tabs. What I would like is for each tab to track its own scroll value separately, so you don't lose your place when switching between them.

I've reduced this to a minimal program that displays the same behavior:

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" ></DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var tab = new Tab();
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                tab.Lines.Add(new Line { Value = (i * 100 + j).ToString() });

            Tabs.Add(tab);
        }
    }

    public class Tab
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Line> Lines { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Line>();
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Any insight into why it's doing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solved my problem (as well as explaining the real cause of my issue)

[Stop TabControl from recreating its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794151/stop-tabcontrol-from-recreating-its-children/9802346#9802346)