# Trouble displaying different cefsharp pages in separate tabs in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am trying to make a browser with tabs in WPF, I have the dynamic tabs but whenever I make a new tabs it makes all the tabs the default address (duckduckgo.com) how would I display a different web page for each tab?

I have a navigation bar with back forward and go buttons, and i'd also like to know how to make the forward and back options exclusive to tabs, i'd guess instead of using things like Browser.CanGoBack I'd have to use the Tab definition instead of the Browser.

The code:

XAML:

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="0">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            </Button>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Button Content="&lt;Back" Name ="backree" Click="backree_Click"> </Button>
                <Button Content="Go" Name ="navixd" Click="navixd_Click"></Button>
                <Button Content="Forward&gt;" Name ="forwardyikes" Click="forwardyikes_Click"></Button>
                <TextBox Name="addbox"></TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
            <cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="StackOverflow.com" FrameLoadEnd="ChromiumWebBrowser_OnFrameLoadEnd" Name="Browser"></cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser>
        </DockPanel>

    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<TabItem> _tabItems;
        private TabItem _tabAdd;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                _tabItems = new List<TabItem>();

                _tabAdd = new TabItem();
                _tabAdd.Header = "+";
                _tabAdd.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tabAdd_MouseLeftButtonUp);

                _tabItems.Add(_tabAdd);

                this.AddTabItem();

                tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

                tabDynamic.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private TabItem AddTabItem()
        {
            int count = _tabItems.Count;

            TabItem tab = new TabItem();

            tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
            tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);
            tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

            Browser.Address = "duckduckgo.com";

            _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab);

            return tab;
        }

        private void tabAdd_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            tabDynamic.DataContext = null;

            TabItem tab = this.AddTabItem();

            tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

            tabDynamic.SelectedItem = tab;
        }

        private void tabDynamic_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem tab = tabDynamic.SelectedItem as TabItem;
            if (tab == null) return;

            if (tab.Equals(_tabAdd))
            {
                tabDynamic.DataContext = null;

                TabItem newTab = this.AddTabItem();

                tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

                tabDynamic.SelectedItem = newTab;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string tabName = (sender as Button).CommandParameter.ToString();

            var item = tabDynamic.Items.Cast<TabItem>().Where(i => i.Name.Equals(tabName)).SingleOrDefault();

            TabItem tab = item as TabItem;

            if (tab != null)
            {
                if (_tabItems.Count < 3)
                {
                    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }
                else
                {
                    TabItem selectedTab = tabDynamic.SelectedItem as TabItem;

                    tabDynamic.DataContext = null;

                    _tabItems.Remove(tab);

                    tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

                    if (selectedTab == null || selectedTab.Equals(tab))
                    {
                        selectedTab = _tabItems[0];
                    }
                    tabDynamic.SelectedItem = selectedTab;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ChromiumWebBrowser_OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
           {
               addbox.Text = e.Url;
               backree.IsEnabled = Browser.CanGoBack;
               navixd.IsEnabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addbox.Text);
               forwardyikes.IsEnabled = Browser.CanGoForward;
           }));
        }


        private void backree_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Browser.CanGoBack)
            {
                Browser.Back();
            }
        }

        private void navixd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addbox.Text))
            {
                Browser.Address = addbox.Text;
            }
        }

        private void forwardyikes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Browser.CanGoForward)
            {
                Browser.Forward();
            }

        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Your browser isn't actually part of the tab. It's defined outside,  is that your intention?  A simple way to encapsulate the browser and all of the related buttons/fields is to create a UserControl.

Comment: The tabs and the browser, based upon this code here, seem to be completely disconnected entities. I think a good start would be to store information like the current address (and maybe navigation history) with each tab; this probably means you'll have to make your own class inheriting the TabItem (i.e. BrowserTabItem : TabItem) where you can create and set these properties. Then have the browser navigate to the selected tab's stored address when the TabControl's selected tab changed. There's of course other ways to do it too, this is just one example of a way to do it.

Comment: One ChromiumWebBrowser instance per tab is the usual approach. Using a single instance and navigating when the tab changes is going to lose any non persisted state e.g page position, text typed, etc

Comment: @amaitland Ah I see, how would i go about this?

Comment: A UserControl to encapsulate your browser and related UI elements is one option see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Views you may also need a custom tabcontrol as detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9802346