# Add tabs to tab control from same DataTemplate but they shouldn't be connected to each other

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

In my wpf program i would like to have tabs that would be generated from array or list. I would like to edit files with each tab. Each tab would have corresponding folder with same name, so all tabs should look same (this is why I used DataTemplates), since files in all directories are all generated with same names but their content is different. I have code that generates tabs from array and adds names to tabs.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            this.Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();

            var location = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

            string[] folderList = new string[] { "Folder1", "Folder2" };

            foreach (string folder in folderList)
            {
                this.Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel(folder));

                string newLocation = location + folder + "\\";//i would like to point tab to this directory

            }
        }
    }

    public class TabViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public TabViewModel(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
```

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBox x:Name="fileTextBox"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

But I have 2 problems:

1. I put textbox in content of a tab and if I create more than 1 tab they all share same content in textbox. I would need to make separate instance for each tab.
2. When tab is created I would need to assign directory(which i stored in newLocation string) to it and then display file (e.g. sample.txt) in textbox (fileTextBox).

Comment: Hi Vito - your code is missing example screenshots. Can you please add the same? Also, some sample of code rendered outside of TabControl may help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you're experiencing this behavior because, when binding by `ItemsSource`, all TabControl items are 'optimized' by sharing a panel to render the content (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794151/stop-tabcontrol-from-recreating-its-children))
2. I suggest you use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your view model and add the file data in the TabViewModel (I added the Location property but you can also add a Content property)

   ```
   public class MainWindowViewModel
   {
   public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }

   public MainWindowViewModel()
   {
       this.Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();

       var location = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

       string[] folderList = new string[] { "Folder1", "Folder2" };

       foreach (string folder in folderList)
       {
           string newLocation = location + folder + "\\";//i would like to point tab to this directory

           this.Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel(folder, newLocation));

       }
   }

   public class TabViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   private string _name;
   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set
       {
           if (_name == value)
             return;
           _name = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   private string _location;
   public string Location
   {
       get { return _location; }
       set
       {
           if (_location == value)
             return;
           _location = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public TabViewModel(string name, string location)
   {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Location = location;
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
       PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
   }
   ```

XAML: 
notice the use of `UpdateSourceTrigger` to update the viewModel when the textbox content changes

```
<TabControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  <DataTemplate >
      <TextBox x:Name="fileTextBox" Text="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```