# Performance when using TabControl in Catel MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, mvvm, tabcontrol, catel

I am using a `Catel` as my primary MVVM framework. In current application I have splited my UI in several Tabs. Each Tab is loading the appropriate `View`. While I am getting expected results I've noticed that by changing each Tab it takes almost `1~3` sec for a View to be shown. Is there a way to speed up this process?

```
<TabItem Header="Tools">
    <catel:StackGrid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Worker">
                <Grid>
                    <Views:WorkerReportView />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Business">
                <Grid>
                    <Views:BusinessReportView />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </catel:StackGrid>
</TabItem>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to improve performance in Catel. You should definitely take a look at the [Performance Considerations](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Performance+considerations).

In the latest version (nightly build, is the upcoming 4.0 version) the team spent a lot of time tweaking performance and introducing a new feature called [ApiCop](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/ApiCop). This feature will generate an advisory report when a debugger is attached, especially when loading views and features are enabled (by default) which aren't being used.

Comment: Hi Geert, I;ve looked at Performance section, but I am really not sure what is causing this behaviour. The very same app without usage of any framewori is performing very fast. Could you pls suggest what can speed up the loading of views?

Comment: First things to try: 

Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl.DefaultSkipSearchingForInfoBarMessageControlValue = true;
Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl.DefaultCreateWarningAndErrorValidatorForViewModelValue = false;
Catel.Data.ModelBase.SuspendValidationForAllModels = true;

Comment: IF it is still not working as expected, please create an official ticket at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker or request private support at http://www.catelproject.com/support/enterprise/

Comment: Nope.. it didn't made any difference,

Comment: The solution was quite crazy. My Tab control was inside plain Grid... once I changed it to CatelGrid, the performance increased mutliple times.

Answer (score 2):

I think, in this case the problem covered not in `Catel`. A standard `TabControl` unloading and reloading the VisualTree of `Content` *every* time when you switching tabs. This means that every time you go to the tab, View is rendered anew, therefore affecting the performance, even more so if View is weighty.

You can see this if you create for the content `Loaded` event handler, like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Worker">                
        <ContentControl Name="Content1" 
                        Loaded="Content1_Loaded" />                    
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Business">               
        <ContentControl Name="Content2"
                        Loaded="Content2_Loaded"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

These events will be triggered every time when you switch between tabs.

As an alternative, you can try the implementation of `TabControl` that loads the content for tabs only once, when the program starts. I found one in this answer:

[How to preserve the full state of the View when navigating between Views in an MVVM application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808076/how-to-preserve-the-full-state-of-the-view-when-navigating-between-views-in-an-m/8809408#8809408)

Here is listing:

**`Class TabControlEx`**

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ItemsHolder", Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class TabControlEx : TabControl
{
    private Panel ItemsHolderPanel = null;

    public TabControlEx()
        : base()
    {
        // This is necessary so that we get the initial databound selected item
        ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If containers are done, generate the selected item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            UpdateSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the ItemsHolder and generate any children
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        ItemsHolderPanel = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHolder") as Panel;
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the items change we remove any generated panel children and add any new ones as necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (ItemsHolderPanel == null)
            return;

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                ItemsHolderPanel.Children.Clear();
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                if (e.OldItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);
                        if (cp != null)
                            ItemsHolderPanel.Children.Remove(cp);
                    }
                }

                // Don't do anything with new items because we don't want to
                // create visuals that aren't being shown

                UpdateSelectedItem();
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Replace not implemented yet");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    private void UpdateSelectedItem()
    {
        if (ItemsHolderPanel == null)
            return;

        // Generate a ContentPresenter if necessary
        TabItem item = GetSelectedTabItem();
        if (item != null)
            CreateChildContentPresenter(item);

        // show the right child
        foreach (ContentPresenter child in ItemsHolderPanel.Children)
            child.Visibility = ((child.Tag as TabItem).IsSelected) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private ContentPresenter CreateChildContentPresenter(object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return null;

        ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);

        if (cp != null)
            return cp;

        // the actual child to be added.  cp.Tag is a reference to the TabItem
        cp = new ContentPresenter();
        cp.Content = (item is TabItem) ? (item as TabItem).Content : item;
        cp.ContentTemplate = this.SelectedContentTemplate;
        cp.ContentTemplateSelector = this.SelectedContentTemplateSelector;
        cp.ContentStringFormat = this.SelectedContentStringFormat;
        cp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        cp.Tag = (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
        ItemsHolderPanel.Children.Add(cp);
        return cp;
    }

    private ContentPresenter FindChildContentPresenter(object data)
    {
        if (data is TabItem)
            data = (data as TabItem).Content;

        if (data == null)
            return null;

        if (ItemsHolderPanel == null)
            return null;

        foreach (ContentPresenter cp in ItemsHolderPanel.Children)
        {
            if (cp.Content == data)
                return cp;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected TabItem GetSelectedTabItem()
    {
        object selectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem == null)
            return null;

        TabItem item = selectedItem as TabItem;
        if (item == null)
            item = base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(base.SelectedIndex) as TabItem;

        return item;
    }
}
```

**`Style`**

I have it a bit modified for better display:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type this:TabControlEx}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        ClipToBounds="True" 
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0" />
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <DockPanel Margin="2,2,0,0" 
                                LastChildFill="False">

                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" 
                                    Margin="0,0,0,-1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                    IsItemsHost="True" 
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
                    </DockPanel>

                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel"
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" 
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">

                        <Grid x:Name="PART_ItemsHolder" 
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**`Some notes`**

Personally, I always use a `DataTemplate` as View. As it turns more dynamic and less impact on performance because UserControl is a "weighty" control, and I realize it is extremely rare - when it is necessary to create a separate control, eg `DatePicker`.

Therefore, as one more piece of advice: if possible, remake your View under DataTemplate and load them into `ContentControl`. I think using a `DataTemplate` and `TabControlEx` can significantly improve the performance of the entire application.

**`Update`**

`Mr.@Geert van Horrik` in comment mentioned that `Catel` does provide this implementation as well as `Catel.Windows.Controls.TabControl`. I think you should to check it out first.

Comment: Catel does provide this implementation as well as Catel.Windows.Controls.TabControl.

Comment: @Geert van Horrik: Okay, good. Honestly, I had no experience with it and with `Catel`. As I understand it, the OP used in his question the standard implementation of `TabControl`, so I thought it might be in this case.